# Flutter Bottom Navigator Scroll up

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a list of blog posts in the body and bottom navigation bar. I have to show the navigator button either page scroll up or down.

[image]

When we click on the button then navigator should pop up. Like this.

[image]

I have written the code but it is not working

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:bottom_drawer/bottom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class DrawerBack extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_DrawerBack createState() => _DrawerBack();

}

class _DrawerBack extends State<DrawerBack> {

  bool isLoading = true;
  SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child:Container(
        child: Column(
          children:[
            buildBottomDrawer(context),
          ]
        ),
      )
  ),
);}

BottomDrawerController controller = BottomDrawerController();

 Widget buildBottomDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  return BottomDrawer(
   header: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        child: Image.asset('assets/image/up_arrow.png', height: 50, width: 50),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/image/Home.png"),
                    Text("Home",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/image/trends.png"),
                    Text("Trends",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/image/port.png"),
                    Text("Portfolio",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/image/coins.png"),
                    Text("Coins",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/image/top.png"),
                    Text("Top Coins",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff8D8D8D),fontFamily: 'Manrope',
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Spacer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),

  headerHeight: 60.0,

  drawerHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *2,

  color: Colors.black,
  cornerRadius: 32,

  controller: controller,
 );}
}
```

So I have write this code when I see internet that we can make this using Bottom Drawer but it is not working I have seen the code on internet also and write the same code but it is not working yet.

So guys you can help me in this.

Comment: how you are using `DrawerBack `

Comment: I have write the code you cans see it. But I have make the class then in the class I'm using it through the widget and that widget I call in the build widget

Comment: Do you get render box issue from current snippet ?

Comment: No, I don't get any render box error from snippet